# Add individual negative numbers from a String

Tags: javascript

```
function sumDigits(num) {
  
  newStr = num.toString();
  var sum = 0;

  for(var i=0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
    
    sum = sum + parseInt(newStr[i]);
  }

  return sum;
}

var output = sumDigits(1148);
console.log(output); // --> 14
```

Hey guys, my output is 14. However, my for loop falls apart if num is a negative number. Anyone got any ideas how to get past this? Presently, a negative number returns 'NaN'

Comment: Use [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) to get the number without the negative sign

Comment: ...and what is your expected output for `-1148` ?

Comment: expected value in this case would be -14 (-1 + -1 + -4 + -8)

Answer (score 0):

One of the examples.

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
  newStr = Math.abs(num).toString();
  var sum = 0;

  for(var i=0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + parseInt(newStr[i]);
  }

  return num >= 0 ? sum : -sum ;
}

var output = sumDigits(1148);
console.log(output); // --> 14
var output = sumDigits(-1148);
console.log(output); // --> -14
var output = sumDigits(0);
console.log(output); // --> 0
```

Comment: When I run that I get this error:

    ✓ should return a number
    ✓ should sum the digits of a positive number
    1) should sum the digits of a negative number
    ✓ should sum return 0 if the number is 0

Comment: As Tim says, it should work. Can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a modulus approach here, which avoids the unnecessary cast from integer to string and vice-versa:

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
    var sum = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        sum += num % 10;
        num = num > 0 ? Math.floor(num / 10) : Math.ceil(num / 10);
    }
    return sum;
}

var output = sumDigits(1148);
console.log("1148  => " + output);
var output = sumDigits(-1148);
console.log("-1148 => " + output);
output = sumDigits(0);
console.log("0     => " + output);
```

Comment: clever solution.

when I run this the problem still wants me "add negative numbers."




✓ should return a number ✓ should sum the digits of a positive number 1) should sum the digits of a negative number ✓ should sum return 0 if the number is 0

Comment: @Brixsta Maybe you need to reload your page, but the answer above meets all three requirements already.

Comment: I agree with you Tim, this does meet the problem requirements. However, the page says this -

In order to use some of the methods that will be most helpful to you, you will most likely want to do some string to number conversion and vice versa.
Be sure to familiarize yourself with the "toString" method, as well as the "Number" function.

Comment: They want us to use the Number function in the problem most likely to allow us to add negative numbers. Frustrating problem

Comment: "you will _most likely_ want" ... that doesn't sound like an ultimatum to me.  I have a policy of usually giving the best possible answer here, rather than catering to the homework assignment.  But, as I see this is homework now, I won't make any further edits.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the result?

```
function sumDigits(input) {
  return Math.abs(input)
    .toString()
    .split("")
    .reduce((sum, num) => sum + Number(num), 0) 
    * (input < 0 ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a negative number into your `sumDigits()` function and convert it to a string, the first character becomes the sign (-). So, you should get the absolute value to get rid of the sign. However, if you're expecting a negative value, then you should define a flag that indicates whether the parameter was a negative integer before it got converted, or simply multiply it again by the initial sign. So, you should modify your function like this:

```js
function sumDigits(num) {
  const seq = Math.abs(num).toString();

  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < seq.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(seq[i]);
  }
  return sum * Math.sign(num);
}
```